# Glassfih and Apache configuration with two NIC cards

Tags: linux, apache, configuration, glassfish-4, nic

I've an Ubuntu 16.04 server with two NIC cards. Both of them are configured with static IP and set to different hosts.
At this time, I've running Apache and glassfish through the same interface (only one of the cards), Apache listen on the port 80 and glassfish the 8080 (classic configuration).

Now I want to enable the second NIC in order to allow glassfish to listen the port 80. This way I'll have Apache listening port 80 of the first NIC and Glassfish the port 80 with the other card and different domain. However I can't accomplish that.

By the moment I've tried the following configurations but neither of them works:

- Creating a new http-listener with port 80 and with address equal to the second nic IP address.
- Creating a virtual server, set the host to the second nic IP address, and then the http-listener with port 80.
- Create a new domain with --keytooloption CN=my.domain.name and with that domain make the two things upon (while creating this domain --instanceport 80 is not permitted, a message said that 80 port is in use, but from my point of view, port 80 is in use but by different interface...?).
- Some different domain.xml adjustments like ports, hosts, etc.

I've been reading Glassfish documentation the last two or three days and didn't find the answer yet.

Both nic cards are on the same net, for example:
111.222.333.1  and the other 111.222.333.2

I didn't try with different sub nets maybe changing the second NIC IP to 111.222.444.2, however I don't have the necessary privileges to make those changes and before ask to the IT people on the company, and change other configurations, I'll like to know if someone of you have ever been on a similar scenario? does anyone have any idea? suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts I get with the right configuration.

**Step 1**

As the server have Apache and Glassfish servers, by default, apache configuration listen port 80 for all IPs, so is the first thing to change:

```
--/etc/apache2/ports.conf 
change line "Listen 80"  by "Listen ###.###.###.###:80" having ###... as the apache desired ip address
Then restart apache
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**Step 2**

Create http-listener for Glassfish on the port 80 for the second IP:

```
 sudo ./asadmin create-http-listener --listeneraddress ###.###.###.### --listenerport 80 --acceptorthreads 16 --securityenabled=false --default-virtual-server server myListenerName
```

**Step 3**

If you already have Glassfish installed (like my case) it was already listening to the previous IP (apache one) but in 8080 port, in order to listen to the new IP, a new virtual server needs to be created:

```
./asadmin create-virtual-server --hosts my.domain.name --networklisteners myListenerName myservername
```

**Step 4**

At the time of http-listener "myListenerName" creation, it needed to be linked to a server, so the only available at that time was the default one: "server". So then manually update domain.xml in order to delete myListenerName from the network-listeners of server and add it to the virtual-server "myservername". At the end it looks like the above:

```
<virtual-server network-listeners="http-listener-1,http-listener-2" id="server"></virtual-server>
    <virtual-server network-listeners="myListenerName" hosts="my.domain.nama" id="myservername"></virtual-server>
```

**Step 5**

Re start glassfish

```
./asadmin stop-domain domain1 
./asadmin start-domain domain1
```

**Step 6**

Deploy any application to the new server

```
./asadmin deploy  --virtualservers myservername /path/to/my.war
```

**Step 7**

Relax

I hope this info helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

If I may, I wrote a blog post on this at:

https://rsoftwareblog.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/glassfish-server-multi-nic-conundrum/

Hope this helps

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)